# Crop lines in R plot with InkScape

Tags: r, svg, plot, inkscape

I have created some plots in `R` using the following code.  The data files are pasted below.  I have not been able to create a picture file to upload here, but the figure can be recreated with this code, the provided data and InkScape instructions below.  I am using Windows.

```
c.low <- read.csv('c.low.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")
e.high <- read.csv('e.high.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")

my.plot <- 'small_plot_with_inkscape_to_crop_lines.svg'

library(Cairo)
CairoSVG(my.plot, onefile = TRUE, pointsize = 12, width=6, height=9, bg="white")
par(mfrow=c(3,2), oma=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), cex.lab=1.0, asp=1)

plot(c.low$TT, c.low$point, xlab = 'TT', ylab = 'C', type = 'l', col = 'green', lwd = 2, lty = 1,
     ylim = c(0, (max(c.low$point)+0.1)), cex.lab = 1.5)
     lines(c.low$TT,  c.low$lower95CI, type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)
     lines(c.low$TT,  c.low$upper95CI, type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)

plot(e.high$TT, e.high$point, xlab = 'TT', ylab = 'E', type = 'l', col = 'green', lwd = 2, lty = 1,
     ylim = c(0, (max(e.high$point)+0.1)), cex.lab = 1.5)
     lines(e.high$TT, e.high$lower95CI, type = 'l', col =  'blue', lwd = 2, lty = 3)
     lines(e.high$TT, e.high$upper95CI, type = 'l', col =  'blue', lwd = 2, lty = 3)

dev.off()
```

I then open the `svg` file with `InkScape` and save the file as an `emf` file.  When saving the `emf` file I select `Convert texts to paths` in the `EMF Output` window.

The problem is that some of the lines in the `emf` file are extending beyond the plot frame when I open the `emf` file in `MSWord`.  These lines are not visible outside the plot frame when viewed in `R` or in `InkScape`.

How can I crop the lines in the `emf` file or otherwise prevent them from being visible outside the plot frame when viewed in `MSWord`?

I have located a similar question here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1405292

Here are the contents of the `c.low.csv` file:

```
point,lower95CI,upper95CI,TT
0.5082851,0.363055,0.6521302,-3.99994974874372
0.5087905,0.3633061,0.6528011,-3.95356783919598
0.5092959,0.363551,0.6534776,-3.90718592964824
0.5098013,0.3637897,0.6541595,-3.8608040201005
0.5103066,0.3640223,0.6548468,-3.81442211055276
0.5108119,0.3642487,0.6555395,-3.76804020100503
0.5113172,0.3644691,0.6562376,-3.72165829145729
0.5118225,0.3646834,0.6569409,-3.67527638190955
0.5123277,0.3648916,0.6576495,-3.62889447236181
0.512833,0.3650939,0.6583633,-3.58251256281407
0.5133382,0.3652902,0.6590821,-3.53613065326633
0.5138433,0.3654805,0.6598061,-3.48974874371859
0.5143485,0.3656649,0.660535,-3.44336683417086
0.5148536,0.3658434,0.6612689,-3.39698492462312
0.5153587,0.3660161,0.6620078,-3.35060301507538
0.5158637,0.366183,0.6627514,-3.30422110552764
0.5163688,0.3663441,0.6634999,-3.2578391959799
0.5168738,0.3664994,0.664253,-3.21145728643216
0.5173787,0.366649,0.6650109,-3.16507537688442
0.5178836,0.3667929,0.6657734,-3.11869346733668
0.5183885,0.3669312,0.6665404,-3.07231155778895
0.5188934,0.3670639,0.6673119,-3.02592964824121
0.5193982,0.3671911,0.6680879,-2.97954773869347
0.5199029,0.3673126,0.6688682,-2.93316582914573
0.5204077,0.3674287,0.6696529,-2.88678391959799
0.5209123,0.3675394,0.6704418,-2.84040201005025
0.521417,0.3676446,0.6712349,-2.79402010050251
0.5219216,0.3677444,0.6720322,-2.74763819095477
0.5224261,0.3678389,0.6728335,-2.70125628140704
0.5229306,0.3679281,0.6736388,-2.6548743718593
0.5234351,0.3680121,0.6744481,-2.60849246231156
0.5239395,0.3680908,0.6752613,-2.56211055276382
0.5244439,0.3681643,0.6760783,-2.51572864321608
0.5249482,0.3682327,0.6768991,-2.46934673366834
0.5254524,0.368296,0.6777235,-2.4229648241206
0.5259567,0.3683542,0.6785517,-2.37658291457286
0.5264608,0.3684074,0.6793834,-2.33020100502513
0.5269649,0.3684557,0.6802186,-2.28381909547739
0.527469,0.368499,0.6810573,-2.23743718592965
0.527973,0.3685374,0.6818994,-2.19105527638191
0.5284769,0.3685709,0.6827448,-2.14467336683417
0.5289808,0.3685996,0.6835935,-2.09829145728643
0.5294846,0.3686236,0.6844454,-2.05190954773869
0.5299884,0.3686428,0.6853004,-2.00552763819096
0.5304921,0.3686573,0.6861585,-1.95914572864322
0.5309957,0.3686672,0.6870197,-1.91276381909548
0.5314993,0.3686725,0.6878838,-1.86638190954774
0.5320028,0.3686732,0.6887508,-1.82
```

Here are the contents of the `e.high.csv` file:

```
point,lower95CI,upper95CI,TT
0.2048022,0.1050293,0.3611121,-11.05
0.2021779,0.1039115,0.356411,-11.0036180904523
0.1995788,0.1028025,0.3517418,-10.9572361809045
0.1970049,0.1017022,0.3471054,-10.9108542713568
0.1944561,0.1006105,0.3425023,-10.864472361809
0.1919324,0.09952735,0.3379333,-10.8180904522613
0.1894337,0.09845275,0.3333989,-10.7717085427136
0.1869601,0.09738664,0.3288999,-10.7253266331658
0.1845114,0.09632895,0.3244367,-10.6789447236181
0.1820876,0.09527966,0.32001,-10.6325628140704
0.1796886,0.09423869,0.3156203,-10.5861809045226
0.1773143,0.09320602,0.3112681,-10.5397989949749
0.1749648,0.09218158,0.3069539,-10.4934170854271
0.1726398,0.09116533,0.3026782,-10.4470351758794
0.1703394,0.09015722,0.2984413,-10.4006532663317
0.1680634,0.0891572,0.2942438,-10.3542713567839
0.1658117,0.08816522,0.2900859,-10.3078894472362
0.1635842,0.08718124,0.2859681,-10.2615075376884
0.1613809,0.0862052,0.2818907,-10.2151256281407
0.1592016,0.08523705,0.2778539,-10.168743718593
0.1570463,0.08427675,0.2738582,-10.1223618090452
0.1549147,0.08332425,0.2699036,-10.0759798994975
0.1528068,0.0823795,0.2659906,-10.0295979899497
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem described in the original post is related to a long-time bug.  I have been able to jerry-rig a solution by cropping lines within `R`.  Below I use `grconvertY` to identify the position of the top border, then use an `ifelse` statement to set elements above that value to `NA`.

People commonly suggest using `"usr"` to identify the position of the top border, but I could not get that option to work given that I am creating two panels in the figure.

The post-processed figure is shown below (after format conversion within `InkScape` and importation to `PowerPoint` [then saved as a `jpeg` for `Stack Overflow`]).

```
T   <- 1:20
x   <- 5 + 0.5 * T
x.u <- 6 + 0.5 * T
x.l <- 4 + 0.5 * T

T2   <- 20:40
x2   <- 40 + 2 * T2
x.u2 <- 60 + 2 * T2
x.l2 <- 20 + 2 * T2

library(Cairo)
CairoSVG('my.plot.svg', onefile = TRUE, pointsize = 12, width=6, height=9, bg="white")

par(mfrow=c(2,1), xpd=NA)

plot(T, x, xlab = 'x', ylab = 'y', type = 'l', col = 'green', lwd = 2, lty = 1,
     ylim = c(0, (max(x)+0.1)), cex.lab = 1.5)

     top.y <- grconvertY(1, from='npc')
     x.u = ifelse(x.u >= top.y, NA, x.u)

     lines(T,  x.u, type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)
     lines(T,  x.l, type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)

plot(T2, x2, xlab = 'x2', ylab = 'y2', type = 'l', col = 'green', lwd = 2, lty = 1,
     ylim = c(0, (max(x2)+0.1)), cex.lab = 1.5)

     top.y <- grconvertY(1, from='npc')
     x.u2 = ifelse(x.u2 >= top.y, NA, x.u2)

     lines(T2,  x.u2, type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)
     lines(T2,  x.l2, type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)

dev.off()
```

[image]